# update assignment applied to set vs row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to randomly update stateid in [address], so i started with this query

```
update [address] 
set stateid = (select top 1 id 
               from lookupvalue 
               where lookuptypeid = 3 and code = 1 
               order by newid()), 
    countryid = 1

select * 
from [address]
```

but as it appears, all the rows get the same value, when I tried referencing [address] table from the inner select query, the update is ran per row (and I got the desired effect).

```
update [address] 
set stateid = (select top 1 id 
               from lookupvalue 
               where lookuptypeid = 3 and [address].id = [address].id 
                 and code = 1
               order by newid()),
    countryid = 1

select * 
from [address]
```

Can someone elaborate on the above behavior, is it related to query plan, do I have to make a dummy reference in the inner select to force the update assignment to be evaluated per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the query plan. SQL Server (and other databases too) see the subquery and decide that it can be optimized away. I consider this an error because `newid()` is a volatile function, so the subquery cannot be optimized away. But, there are arguments on the other side as well.

Putting in the outer reference fixes the problem, so you know how to get around this "optimization".

Comment: Would you ever advise on doing the above though? I can't help but feel this is less than obvious code. Having a join in your update seems the more 'logical' approach, no?

Comment: @Jens . . . I do worry that the optimizer might get smarter one day and realize that the correlation clause is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate result per row you can also use CROSS APPLY